# require function parameter to implement multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript

In typescript, is it possible to do something of the sort:

```
module module1 {
    export interface Foo {
        data1: string;
    }
    export interface Bar {
        data2: string;
    }
    export function foobar(data: Foo & Bar) {
        //do stuff
        data.data1; data.data2;
    }
}
```

Namely, force foobar's data parameter to implement both Foo and Bar? And if so, what is the correct syntax?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to make a new named interface:

```
module module1 {
    export interface Foo {
        data1: string;
    }
    export interface Bar {
        data2: string;
    }
    export interface FooAndBar extends Foo, Bar { }
    export function foobar(data: FooAndBar) {
        //do stuff
        data.data1; data.data2;
    }
}
```