# Multiple Class Inheritance In TypeScript

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, interface, typescript

What are ways to get around the problem of only being allowed to extend at most one other class.

```
class Bar {

  doBarThings() {
    //...
  }

}

class Bazz {

  doBazzThings() {
    //...
  }

}

class Foo extends Bar, Bazz {

  doBarThings() {
    super.doBarThings();
    //...
  }

}
```

This is currently not possible, TypeScript will give an error. One can overcome this problem in other languages by using interfaces but solving the problem with those is not possible in TypeScript.

Suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Related: multiple interfaces inheritance is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766032/require-function-parameter-to-implement-multiple-interfaces question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with interfaces:

```
interface IBar {
  doBarThings();
}

interface IBazz {
  doBazzThings();
}

class Foo implements IBar, IBazz {
  doBarThings() {}
  doBazzThings(){}
}
```

But if you want implementation for this in a `super`/`base` way, then you'll have to do something different, like this:

```
class FooBase implements IBar, IBazz{
  doBarThings() {}
  doBazzThings(){}
}

class Foo extends FooBase {
  doFooThings(){
      super.doBarThings();
      super.doBazzThings();
  }
}
```

Comment: But this is not multiple inheritance, this is a single implementation of multiple interfaces, which is not the same thing. Multiple inheritance includes inheritance of implementation.

Comment: Of course it isn't multiple inheritance, TypeScript does not support it (just like C# & Java). But what I have provided, as requested by the OP are a couple of alternatives to mimic that functionality.

Comment: is there a way to have an interface provide a default implementation (like Java, for example)? that would really match 100% what the op was asking

Answer (score 2):

This is my workaround on extending multiple classes. It allows for some pretty sweet type-safety. I have yet to find any major downsides to this approach, works just as I would want multiple inheritance to do.

First declare interfaces that you want to implement on your target class:

```
interface IBar {
  doBarThings(): void;
}

interface IBazz {
  doBazzThings(): void;
}

class Foo implements IBar, IBazz {}
```

Now we have to add the implementation to the `Foo` class. We can use class mixins that also implements these interfaces:

```
class Base {}

type Constructor<I = Base> = new (...args: any[]) => I;

function Bar<T extends Constructor>(constructor: T = Base as any) {
  return class extends constructor implements IBar {
    public doBarThings() {
      console.log("Do bar!");
    }
  };
}

function Bazz<T extends Constructor>(constructor: T = Base as any) {
  return class extends constructor implements IBazz {
    public doBazzThings() {
      console.log("Do bazz!");
    }
  };
}
```

Extend the `Foo` class with the class mixins:

```
class Foo extends Bar(Bazz()) implements IBar, IBazz {
  public doBarThings() {
    super.doBarThings();
    console.log("Override mixin");
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.doBazzThings(); // Do bazz!
foo.doBarThings(); // Do bar! // Override mixin
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution to your problem, but it is worth to consider to use composition over inheritance anyway.

[Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance?rq=1)