# class hierarchy in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have following class hierarchy:

```
class BaseList {}

class SortableList extends BaseList {}

class EditableList extends BaseList {}

class EditableSortableList extends [Sotrable and Editable]
```

So I'd like to inherit/produce/mix somehow Sotrable and Editable classes into EditableSortableList, the question is how?

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513594/multiple-class-inheritance-in-typescript) is similar problem solved with interfaces, but interfaces do not solve code duplication issue I'm trying to solve building this hierarchy.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no multiple inheritance in typescript. I would suggest you look into mixins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check [Mixins in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html)

> **Note:** Is important to notice that neither multiple inheritance nor mixins are part of the language specification in `TypeScript`. Mixins here is just a pattern.

This way you can have

```
class EditableSortableList implements SortableList, EditableList {
    //Properties and empty methods of both SortableList and EditableList only to satisfy the interfaces. They will be overridden in the next line.
}

applyMixins(EditableSortableList, [SortableList, EditableList]);
```

With `applyMixins` helper method being the following

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
    baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
            derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you mixins worked well for me. My case was a bit more complex, than described above - I have generic abstract classes with different constructors, so I had to change them a bit, however finally I've got what I was looking for!