# How to declare a typescript property that implements multiple interfaces

Tags: typescript

Say I have 2 interfaces:

```
interface Interface1{}
interface Interface2{}
```

is there a way to declare a property as implementing both interfaces? Something like:

```
class MyClass{
  public p: Interface1, Interface2
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> is there a way to declare a property as implementing both interfaces? Something like:

Yup. An `intersection type`:

```
interface Interface1{}
interface Interface2{}
class MyClass{
  public p: Interface1 & Interface2
}
```

## More

- TypeScript Intersection Types: https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system#intersection-type

Comment: the link is now dead

Comment: @AntoineWeber The link is now again _ALIVE!!!_ But it's also available [at archive.org here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230330052341/https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system#intersection-type). Maybe it was having a bad day.

Answer (score 4):

```
interface Interface1 { }
interface Interface2 { }
interface ICombination extends Interface1, Interface2 { };
class MyClass {
    public p: ICombination
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but a disadvantage is that as the number of interfaces increases, the number of combinations grows very quickly. Depending on the use case it might not be a problem, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766032/require-function-parameter-to-implement-multiple-interfaces